# Athena query on paramterized s3 folders

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have the below s3 path for athena

```
<bucket>/prod/dept=sales/year=2020/month=may
```

i created athena table till the prod folder, how do i query a particular department and a year to limit athena scan to a department for faster results.

As we have 1000's of departments spanned to multiple years.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have to either manually add each partition using the [ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html) syntax or - and this is my preferred solution - [Configure a Glue crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) on the bucket and let it create the partitions for you.

Then each partition attribute will get it's own special column in the table, which you can use in your queries to cut down on the data being scanned. The documentation has an example for that: [Preparing Partitioned and Nonpartitioned Data for Querying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html#partitions-preparing-data).

Comment: checking the example ..thanks Maurice for the help..will accept once reviweing the example